# Assign multiple selection column list item with a quantity?

Tags: 2010

I have created a Parent List that has a multiple selection checkbox for "Media Type". If a user chooses multiple media types, I want user to add a quantity to each media type selected. I am using SharePoint 2010.  I am a novice so I am somewhat limited to SPD, InfoPath and using "simple" code of the brilliant SP developers from internet searches.
Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I think the key here is probably using Infopath to set some rules and then generate muliple text fields for each checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SharePoint lists work in single rows and don't allow multiple complex sub records for individual items. It's a huge limitation that still exists in 2013 and I can't see anything in the road map that suggests this basic need will be introduced in the next version.

I would advise against InfoPath because it's been deprecated. I would similarly advise against modifying the list form views themselves as this can lead to any number of strange quirks.

You have several client-side options, all of which will require a custom form and use of the JSOM (JavaScript Object Model). You can achieve this using a single list but two would allow you to add a worflow to the Master list that included the media orders created in the second list.

Single list approach (making several assumptions):

1. In your list include columns for Customer Name (**Peron or Group**, or **Single Line of Text** if not in AD), Order Date (Date and Time), Media (Choice->Checkbox) and Quantity (Number).
2. Create a new view and Group by Customer Name, order by Created.
3. Create a new page in the same site and name it Orders or whatever is appropriate.
4. Add a Script Editor web part to the page and either embed or link to (preferred) your code.

Your code would include a form with Customer Name and Order Date, and a table with a row for each Media Types (and Quantity) underneath. Each row in this table will represent a new item (row) in your list.

Use the ClientContext library to lookup the list. Generate the table above by querying the list's Media field and creating a new row for each value. The Quantity field is just a plain input field.

Use jQuery to iterate over the table rows and create an object array for each row that contains a Quantity. You'd also want to validate these fields to ensure a valid numeric value.

Then just create a new list item for each row returned.

Clearly it's outside the scope of this reply to include fully-functional code without actually building the solution. But the example below should hopefully give you a head start.

```
<!-- Add reference to jQuery-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Variables


$(document).ready(function () {
    // Initialise the function after sp.js and ClientContext is ready.
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', GetContextListAndField);
});

// Get context, list and required fields
function GetContextListAndField() {

    var ctx;
    var list;
    var field;

    // Get current context
    ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    // Get the list
    list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Orders")
    ctx.load(list);
    // Get the choice field
    field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Media");
    field = ctx.castTo(field, SP.FieldChoice);
    ctx.load(field);

    // Execute query
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.BuildForm),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailure)
    );

}

function BuildForm(sender, args) {

    var form = $('#myForm');

    var clientName = '<p>Full Name: <input type="text" id="name" /></p>';
    var orderDate = '<p>Order Date: <input type="text" id="date" /></p>';
    var table = $('#myTable');
    var submit = '<p><button id="Submit" type="button">Send Order</button></p>';

    $('#myForm').append(clientName);
    $('#myForm').append(orderDate);

    // Build table only if it doesn't already exist
    if (!table.length) {

        var tableHTML = '<table id="myTable"><tr><th>Media</th><th>Quantity</th></tr></table>';

        // Get arry of possible choices
        var choices = field.get_choices();

        // Populate table
        $.each(choices, function (text) {
            $('#myTable').append('<tr class="mediaRow"><td class="mediaType">' + text + '</td><td class="mediaVal"><input /></td></tr>');
        });

        // Append table to form
        $('#myForm').append(tableHTML)
    }

    $('#myForm').append(submit);

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        createListItems(list);
    });
}

function createListItems(list) {

    var client = $('#myForm #name');
    var date = $('#myForm #date');

    var row = $('tr.mediaRow');
    var count = 0;

    row.each(function() {
        var type = $(this).children('.mediaType').text();
        var quantity = $(this).children('.mediaVal input').text();
        if (quantity !== "") {
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            listItem.set_item(client, date, type, quantity);
            listItem.update();
            count++;
        }
    });

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert(count + 'items have been added to your order.');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


function onFailure(sender, e) {
    alert('Failed:' + e.get_message() + '\n' + e.get_stackTrace());
}


</script>

<!-- Form placeholder -->
<div id="myForm"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box having such behavior is not offered by any component. You could however opt for:

1. Change the Edit form into an InfoPath and rely on few Action rules
   and Formatting rules you could decide to toggle visibility on the
   "Media-Type" to store data, see here to get started http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/infopath-with-sharepoint-2010---use-the-edit-form-on-the-list-page.aspx and here to Show/Hide fields based on conditions http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/hide-or-disable-a-control-based-on-values-in-a-form-HP001096364.aspx
2. Customize the EDIT Form to include some JavaScript code to show/hide (see here http://sharepointsherpa.com/2008/08/26/sharepoint-2007-hiding-fields-on-newformaspx-and-editformaspx-the-easy-way/)

In both cases, you should probably create additional columns for each quantity you need to store per record.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are saying.  However, I don't see a way with the above suggestions to fulfil my customers needs. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: you would need to store data in a custom list, which allows edit forms either custom or InfoPath based - the "window" to your data. the shape of the form is up to you to design (more complex would require Web-Part). Either of the 2 options allows for custom interaction (hide/show various form elements - text boxes, etc.).